# How can I disable multiple versions in the Crashlytics Dashboard?

Tags: android, crashlytics

So we use crashlytics extensively in our app. So much so, in fact, that we have every version we build (we change the version number in gradle so that we get something like `3.1.1-ALPHA-fec300`, with a commit hash). Unfortunately, many of these builds aren't used any longer. I can go through and remove the builds from the app's settings page, but it's a time-consuming process, since I have to flip the switch for each one, which gives me a popup and requires me to interact a bit with the UI.

We have over 54 pages of old versions that I'd like to get rid of. Is there a way to mass delete a bunch of them (e.g. all the ones that aren't pinned or some other switch)?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do any type of administration on Fabric/Crashlytics in any type of automated fashion :( As far as I can tell, there is no API available and no mass-actions either. I hope someone else has a better answer!

Comment: I don't know how much this helps, but you can contact Crashlytics support, and they apparently have a method of mass-deleting versions. Unfortunately, you have to describe to them which ones you want to delete, which isn't ideal, either.